# Found error on using list in scala

Tags: scala

I am using Scala for studying purpose 
I wrote this code to sort the elements in list

```
def isort(xs:List[Int]):List[Int]=
xs match{
 case List() => xs
 case y::ys => insert(y,isort(ys))
}
 def insert(x:Int,xs:List[Int]):List[Int]=
xs match{
 case List() => List(x)
case y::ys => if(x<y) x::xs else y :: insert(x,ys)

  }
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Constructor can not be instantiated to expected type found Scala.collection.Immutable required List[Int]
 in  
 `y::ys => insert(y,isort(ys))`
```

and similar error where I use ::

I refer tutorial : https://class.coursera.org/progfun-005/lecture

Comment: i got my error .I define a similar class name in my package and it taking that class as a reference and so it does not know about method ::

Answer (score 1):

Try using the paste mode of the REPL.  This will allow you to define the two defs in the same context:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def isort(xs:List[Int]):List[Int]=
xs match{
 case List() => xs
 case y::ys => insert(y,isort(ys))
}
 def insert(x:Int,xs:List[Int]):List[Int]=
xs match{
 case List() => List(x)
case y::ys => if(x<y) x::xs else y :: insert(x,ys)

  }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

isort: (xs: List[Int])List[Int]
insert: (x: Int, xs: List[Int])List[Int]
```